# android: onUpgrade on sqlite wont work for me

Tags: android

I add new column on my database (i have data on this database)

I have this code:

```
@Override 
public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
    if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
        db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE MEN ADD COLUMN New_Pulse INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
    }
}
```

but it wont work, from where I get the oldVersion and the newVersion ?

For now I done this:

```
try{
    db.execSQL("ALTER TABLE MEN ADD COLUMN New_Pulse INTEGER DEFAULT 0");
}
catch (Exception e) {
    // TODO: handle exception
}
```

it work for me - but I know that its Ugly solution

Comment: Please try to print log of oldVersion and newVersion and see what you get . Have you declare database version in your Database class ? Do you manually changed that or add some details to table schema ?

Comment: check that onUpgrade is called or not?And Have you manually increase DATABASE version or not before add change in table schema.

Answer (score 0):

You don't have to do the check yourself; SQLiteOpenHelper does that automatically! When you enter a higher version number than before, the helper calls `onUpgrade()` method, where you should handle what to do on upgrade.

```
....
....
mySqlHelper = new mySqlHelper (context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

private static class MySQLHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {

    public MySqlHelper(Context context, String name, CursorFactory factory, int version) {
        super(context, name, factory, version);
    }

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // upgrade code.. 
        // drop tables
        onCreate(db);
    }
}
```